# a SVG span inside a link not working in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, svg

Needed to add `<span>` in between `<a>` and SVG, so that a javascript can call out the SVG inline from another file. Everything working, but not in IE, is there anything I missed?? (when testing in IE, it didn't even know that is a link, nothing clickable, and I also have a hover effect too, but nothing show up in IE.) putting together a final code example after the javascript loaded the inline SVG together.

```css
.icon svg{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 3rem;
  height: 3rem;
  margin: 0;
  stroke-width: 1.5;
  stroke-linecap: round;
}

.icon-black svg{
 stroke: #1A1A1A;
 }
```

```html
<a href="#">
<span class="icon icon-black" id="icon-arrow">
<svg id="icon-arrow" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" fill="none" stroke-linejoin="arcs"><path d="M12 19V6M5 12l7-7 7 7"/>
</svg>
</span>
</a>
```

Comment: What's your IE browser version? I have tried to test your code, it seems that your code works well on IE 9+ browser. The result [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zg5cK.gif).

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed, I missed set the `<span>` as display: inline-block;